# Do the notes scattered through levels serve any purpose?

Tags: metro-last-light

Strangely, I've been finding Artyom's current thoughts written down in places he's never been to. Ignoring how ridiculous that is, does finding these notes serve any purpose other than enriching the story?

Comment: I don't think that he is finding pages, but more writing in his journal at those times. You also get the same flashes that signified turning points in Metro 2033, which led to alternative endings. So I suspect (though I haven't reached the end) that getting more of them leads to different endings.

Comment: @Draedalus that certainly sounds less insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Draedalus mentioned, there are alternate endings which you can achieve by doing "good".

However, collecting his notes isn't counting as doing good, so this has no influence on the kind of ending you will see.

Here is a [guide](http://www.gamesradar.com/metro-last-light-alternate-ending-guide-and-walkthrough/) that tells you what to do in order to get an alternate ending. Notes aren't mentioned there.